# Cамый быстрый метод отправки запроса на python

Tags: python, запрос

Подскажите какой модуль сможет отправлять самые быстрые запросы и получать с них данные. Если что grequest отпадает сразу так как там вроде нету получение данных с сайта (html). Буду благодарен за ответ

Comment: "получение данных с сайта (html)"  вы для начала с документацие grequest ознакомьтесь для приличия, прежде чем что-то писать.

Comment: @СергейШашко я смотрел там написано только про получение статуса запроса

Comment: @СергейШашко если есть возможность получение то прошу вас показать мне его

Comment: библиотека grequest использует библиотеку request https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests/blob/master/requirements.txt.

Comment: @СергейШашко да но он не имеет "значение" .text как у request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ответ. Так как в коментах код не читабелен

```
import grequests

urls = [
    'http://python-tablib.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]
request = (grequests.get(url) for url in urls)
b = grequests.map(request)
for data_page in b:
    print(data_page.text)
    print('-'*20)
```